# Как реализовать вывод из словаря value начиная с максимального key в алфавитном порядке?

Tags: python, словари

Несколько команд участвуют в турнире по игре «Что? Где? Когда?». Согласно регламенту турнира, в финал проходит половина команд (с округлением вверх), набравшие больше правильных ответов, чем остальные. Помогите жюри сформировать итоговый протокол.

**Формат ввода**

На первой строке указано натуральное число N — количество команд.

Далее следует описание результатов N команд в произвольном порядке. Данные о каждой команде записываются на двух строках: на первой — название команды, на второй — количество правильных ответов. Гарантируется, что количество правильных ответов у всех команд разное.

**Формат вывода**

Нужно вывести на отдельных строках сначала в алфавитном порядке названия всех команд, вышедших в финал (т. е. команд из лучшей по количеству ответов половины), а затем названия всех остальных команд (также на отдельных строках в алфавитном порядке).

вот код, получается он добавляет в словарь , а нужно сейчас как то реализовать вывод только половины команд от общего кол-ва, начиная с максимального результата(в данном примере это две) в алфавитном порядке и потом на отдельных строках остальных команд, которые не вышли в финал тоже в алфавитном порядке

```
n = int(input())
mass = {}
for i in range(n):
  name = input()
  res = int(input())
  mass[res] = name
  n -= 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `n -= 1` для чего?

Comment: @Zhihar понял, что не нужно было это писать , это ведь цикл for, совсем уже запрограммировался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import math

data = [("Муми-тролли", 15), ("Снорки", 20), ("Хемули-ЧГКшник", 24), ("Хемули -- не ЧГКшники", 1), ("Тофсла и Вифсла", 9), ("Морра", 5), ("Ондатр", 13)]

# отсортировать список команд по убыванию очков
data.sort(key=lambda obj: -obj[1])

# определить кол-во победивших команд
border = math.ceil(len(data) / 2)

# получить список команд победителей и проигравших, легсографически отсортированных
winners = sorted(data[:border], key=lambda obj: obj[0])
loosers = sorted(data[border:], key=lambda obj: obj[0])

# вывести итоговый список
print(*map(lambda obj: obj[0], winners + loosers), sep='\n')
```

Comment: а как тогда в data добавлять элементы? просто у вас в виде списка же и внутри скобочки

Comment: ну вы даете, а как вы хотели задачу решать тогда? - я просто сформировал список кортежей - вы вот в своем примере пихали данные в словарь, а я в список `data.append((input(), input()))`, а код такой привел - потому что отлаживался на нем, чтобы постоянно не вводить

Comment: выдает ошибку на вашу вторую строку где написано -obj[1]  bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Comment: у меня все верно выдает - проверьте что вы в data пишите - вам же надо очки в числа переводить, т.е. `int(input())` делать (скорректировал код чуть-чуть алгоритма - возьмите новый)

Comment: при следующем тесте выдает неверный результат

Comment: фото теста добавил в вопрос

Comment: это я условие задачи прочитал не совсем верно - подумал, что победителей надо вывести в порядке убывания очков, а проигравших в алфавитном порядке, а оказалось и тех и тех в алфавитном - скорректировал код - там по сути 1 строчку поменять